# Docusign Payment Gateway without a Number tab

Tags: docusignapi

We are and have been using the esignature API for about 5 years.  About 2 years ago, we added in the ability to use the docusign payment gateway through use of an example which used a number tab and a formula tab to create the functionality during the signing process.  However, the number tab which is one place that holds amount we want to collect, is always visible and in our case, we do not want it visible.  I then took out the number tab and made the formula just the chargeable amount.  That works fine except that we now get a warning that says:
"There is a discrepancy between the payment items and the total. ..."

What we would like is to either be able to hide the number tab so it is not visible on the document or not use a numbertab and not have the above warning.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the font color to white if your document has white background (most documents) and then white over white - it's invisible. Here is how you do that from the UI, but you can do that from the eSignature API too:

[image]

Comment: We are doing everything through the API.  Can you point me to where the documentation is to change the text color of the number tab within the API?  I can find anywhere on the developer site where there is schema information for this.

Comment: Found the documentation.  Fixed using the suggestion to put the number at the upper left corner of the 1st page of the document and make the text color white.  The xml tag is fontColor btw.